# Bash script to delete Google cloud storage bucket does not work on the list of buckets

Tags: bash, shell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I am running the following command in bash to list all google cloud stoarage buckets that matches a specific pattern and delete all of them except one that is created at last. When running the below command I get the error:
ERROR: (gcloud.storage.rm) The following URLs matched no objects or files: gs://bucketname/

Actually this bucket do exists, and for the loop defined, it is deleting the last entry in the loop.( I should not use gsutil, so I am using gcloud storage command)

```
#!/bin/bash
currentbucket_name=$(gcloud storage ls -b | sort -k2 -r | head -n 1);
echo $currentbucket_name
# List all the previously created  buckets
all_buckets=$(gcloud storage ls -b gs://location-environmentname*);
# Iterate through the buckets and delete all except the current latest bucket
echo "$all_buckets" | while IFS= read -r older_bucket; do
    if [ "$older_bucket" != "gs://${currentbucket_name}/" ]; then
       gcloud storage rm -r "$older_bucket" --no-user-output-enabled && echo "Deleted the Bucket: $older_bucket" || echo "Failed to delete Bucket: $older_bucket.";
    fi
done;
```

Comment: I tried running your script verbatim (swapped out `location-environmentname*` for a real prefix I had buckets in). It worked fine for me when there were matches, and it failed when there were no matches. Are you sure that you have buckets beginning with the prefix `location-environmentname` that belong to the project for which `gcloud storage` is configured to use by default?

Comment: Add `set -x` near the top of the script. You will see each line of code that the shell is going to execute without env-var, cmd-substituion, paramter substitution/expansion and then the actual line the shell has assembled to execute (all env-vars etc substituted) preceded by `+` char. You may see that your `gloud` cmds have some expansions that aren't working as you expect.  Good luck.

Comment: Remove the trailing /. I think it's the problem

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this and avoid the variables

```
gcloud storage ls -b gs://location-environmentname* | \
    grep -v "gs://${currentbucket_name}/" | \
    xargs -I '{}' -L1 gcloud storage rm -r '{}' --no-user-output-enabled
```